# Checkout flow broken

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm trying to make a webshop with commerce 2.0 in Drupal 8.

But when I have added a product to the cart, and I've filled in the Payment Information pane, and I press "Continue to review", the same page is being reloaded and there's a duplicate of the product I tried to purchase.

So I'm stuck in the check out flow.
If I disable the Payment Information pane, then I can continue in the checkout flow, but then I'm missing the payment information.

Does anyone have an idea for a work around or a fix? or maybe knows what's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was because of a module called commerce_variation_cart_form.
After uninstalling it, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to go into the Product Variation Type -> Manage Display

On the "Summary" tab, the Add to Cart field was displaying.  I disabled it and now I can place orders.